# Ingress backend shows unhealthy in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-nodeport

I am trying to expose my application on classic ALB on GCP through ingress. I've created a Nodeport service below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ofamily-service-np
spec:
  selector:
    app: o-famil
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

I have also created managedCertificate object:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: duckdns
spec:
  domains:
    - ofamily.duckdns.org
```

Here's my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: o-family-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "duckdns"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "ingress"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ofamily.duckdns.org
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: ofamily-service-np
            port:
              number: 8000
```

It creates a LoadBalancer

[image]

in the LoadBalancer it shows Network endpoint group details which shows unhealthy, I am unable to troubleshoot.

[image]

I am trying to expose my application on classic ALB on GCP through ingress. I've created a Nodeport service and ingress.yaml but the backend shows unhealthy. I am using GKE Autopilot cluster.

The same application works on loadbalancer service type but when I use Nodeport and ingress, it shows unhealthy.

Do I need to change something in the application or add readiness/liveliness probe in deployment or ingress?

[ingress-error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCl3d.png)[ingress-error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DLEx.png)

Comment: can you share more detail of the load balancer health check? For the health checks to succeed, the pod must be able to respond with a success criteria (default is HTTP request to / if you don't specify any, so make sure that your application accept / request) on the path, protocol and port configured in the health check.
In the mean time, make sure that the Pod is running and healthy. One other test is to curl directly against the NodePort to ensure that the application is accepting traffic.

Comment: Hello Gang, the application is running on / when I create a loadbalancer service for it. Regarding more loadbalancer details, I have attached a screenshot in the original thread above (ingress-error1), it shows this on console.

Comment: from your load balancer console page, can you click the "health check - view health check detail"? be helpful to see the generated healthcheck configuration.